# How to put links on the same line with space in between them?

Tags: html, css

I'd like to be able to put the links that are in my footer section on the same line with some space in between them. I tried using "display: inline", but I couldn't get it to work. Can someone show me how to do it properly please?

```css
/*
 Project name: Portal Hyperlinks
 Author: Justus Self
 Date: 2/26/2017
*/

a:link {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: DarkBlue;
 text-align: center;
}

a:visited {
 color: blue;
}

a:focus {
 font-color: white;
 background-color: MediumBlue;
 font-size: 1.3em;
}

.accent {
 font-weight: bold;
 font-variant: small-caps;
 font-size: 1.4em;
}
```

```html
<!--
 Project name: Portal Hyperlinks
 Author: Justus Self
 Date: 2/26/2017
-->


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>


<head>
 <title> About Us </title>
 <meta charset="utf-8"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
 <h1>About Ozarks Technical Community College</h1>
 
 <p>Ozarks Technical Community College (OTC) was founded April 3, 1990 when the residents of Springfield school district and 
    13 surrounding public school districts voted to establish a "community technical college." Since that time, OTC has continued 
    to uphold a core-set of values that include quality, opportunity, accessibility, learning, diversity, innovation, community, 
    respect, integrity and personal growth. We uphold a mission to promote student learning through accessible, high-quality, 
    affordable workforce training, and technical and general education that is responsive to the educational needs of the community 
    and its diverse constituencies.<p>
 
 <h3>OTC's Strategic Goals</h3>
 <br/>
 <p> Want more information? <a href="mailto:js0877658@otc.edu"> E-mail OTC.</a></p>
 <p><span class="accent">Quality</span>: The quality of the faculty, staff, administration and facilities will be enhanced in order to promote continuous 
    responsiveness to the expanding learning needs of the community.</p>
    <p><span class="accent">Effectiveness</span>: The effectiveness of all programs and services will be continuously assessed to ensure integrity and quality are 
    maintained and improved.</p>
    <p><span class="accent">Community Collaboration</span>: Meaningful relationships within the College's service areas will be formed, allowing OTC to develop 
    new programs that reflect the educational needs of the community stakeholders.</p>
    <p><span class="accent">Retention and Graduation Rates</span>: The College will encourage faculty, staff and administration to continually strive to improve 
    the rate of student retention and graduation.</p>
 <p><span class="accent">Graduate Performance</span>: The College will promote high academic standards that will serve to enhance the success of graduates at 
    the workplace and in transfer institutions.</p>
    <p<span class="accent">Innovation</span>: The College will provide innovative teaching strategies that promote continued learning opportunities for students.</p>
    <p><span class="accent">Affordability</span>: The College will provide affordable learning opportunities to all community members.<p>
    <p><span class="accent">Learning Centered</span>: The College will promote a learning-centered environment that focuses on students' needs and reduces barriers to 
   student success.</p>
   
 <br/>
 <br/>  
 
 <footer>
  <h4><a href="index.html"> Portal </h4>
  <h4><a href="page2.html"> Classes </h4>
 </footer>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

You want the `h4` elements, which are normally `block` to be `inline` instead. Then you can use horizontal (left/right) margin or padding to space them out. You also need to close your `a` tags.

```css
footer h4 {
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 1em;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <h4><a href="index.html">Portal</a></h4>
  <h4><a href="page2.html">Classes</a></h4>
</footer>
```

Comment: Thanks. This was the best solution. My biggest problem was just not writing the h4 after I wrote footer. The closing a tags weren't a problem, though I would have caught them after I validated. Thanks for such a quick response.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```css
    footer{text-align:center;}
    footer h4{
    display: inline;
    margin-right: 10px;
      margin-left:10px;
    }
```

```html
<div style="height:100px;"></div>
<footer style="background:yellow;">
   <h4><a href="index.html">Portal</a></h4>
   <h4><a href="page2.html">Classes</a></h4>
</footer>
```

Comment: The links are wrapped in block level elements (`h4`'s), so this will not put them on the same line.

Comment: Yes firstly i think he used inline for links.

Comment: sorry, what do you mean firstly used inline? They have `h4`'s wrapping both links, so the CSS you gave will not put them on the same line, so it will not put space between them horizontally.

Comment: He said *I tried using "display: inline* So he new that he need to inline. therefore i did not wrote it. Firstly i said remove `inline` because i did not see the `h4`s, then i see and removed the **remove inline** i had writen. Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: They said *"I tried using "display: inline", but I couldn't get it to work."* Which means we need to help them to get it to work. Right now your answer does not do either of the things they're asking - 1) put both links on the same line, and 2) create space between them. So your answer doesn't  help. You can, however, edit your answer so that it does help and provide a correct solution...

Answer (score 0):

Just put them into the same parent element and define a margin-right for the first `a` tag:

```
<footer>
    <h4><a href="index.html" style="margin-right: 50px;">Portal</a><a href="page2.html">Classes</a></h4>
</footer>
```

BTW You forgot to close your `a` tags

Comment: Why would you add a span, and not just put the margin on the link itself? Seems like the span is unnecessary markup here.

Answer (score 0):

```
<footer>
    <h4><a href="index.html" style="margin-right: 20px">Portal</a><a href="page2.html">Classes</a></h4>
</footer>
```

Definitely want to close your anchor tags, and rather than use two h4 tags and then have to override their default behavior, just enclose both links within the same h4. Then, just modify the margin-right to create whatever size space you'd like between the links.

Answer (score 0):

A simple answer is to remove the `<h4>` tag from the footer links. `<h4>` is a block element.

```
<footer>
  <a href="index.html"> Portal</a>
  <a href="page2.html"> Classes </a>
</footer>
```

Then, if you want to style these links to be bigger, use CSS like below.

```
footer a {
  display:inline;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight:bold;
  margin-right:1.5em;
}
```

**Output**

[image]